# Setting custom key when pushing new data to firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fire-sharp

Well, I am new to Firebase and I want to have my own keys while pushing new data to database.

Problem:

```
FireBase.push().setValue(mapped_values);
```

This gives structure like below:

[image: database output]

How can I create my own custom key there?
Such as username or something.

Answer (score 146):

Calling `push()` will generate a key for you.

If instead you use `child()`, you can determine the key/path yourself.

```
ref.child("Victor").setValue("setting custom key when pushing new data to firebase database");
```

Comment: He didn't mark it as an answer because it does not answer his question since Firebase generates automatically a child with a random key whatever you push or set into the database.

Comment: @FrenchyNYC Not if you use `.child('customkey')...`

Comment: And how to do it with angularfire2?

Comment: @trojan setting in the constructor: constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) you can do: this.db.database.ref().child('somechild').set('somevalue')

Comment: How would you do this for an array of data with custom ids? push() can take a dictionary of data, but child() cannot

Comment: in 2020, `set()` should be used instead of `setValue()`

Answer (score 9):

```
        String key="1234567sdfsf8";
        //custom object
        User user=new User();
        DatabaseReference mDatabase;
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.child("Users").child(key).setValue(user);
```

Comment: if key key doesn't exists, it throws an error, because setValue is not defined

Answer (score 7):

As an update to the top answer, the [Firebase API has been changed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) and `setValue()` does not work anymore. Now you must use the `set()` function instead:

```
ref.child("Victor").set("setting custom key when pushing new data to firebase database");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom key using **setValue()** even if the root contains many children
for example if 'Users' is the root and you want to add users with email as a key it will be like this

```
firebase.child("firebase url").child("Users").child("user_1 email").setValue(...)

firebase.child("firebase url").child("Users").child("user_2 email").setValue(...)
```

etc

Answer (score 2):

let's say your db look like

```
 "BookShelf" : {
    "book1" : {
      "bookName" : "book1_push"
       ...
     }
```

your code to be (don't use push(), push() generate a random key)

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Book data = new Book();
mDatabase.child("BookShelf").child("book1").setValue(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) :

```
private static final CollectionReference usersCollection = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users");

User user = new User("MyUsername", "MyPictureUrl");
String userKey = "1234567sdfsf8";

usersCollection.document(userKey).set(user); //MAGIC LINE
```

Answer (score 1):

In POST request it will generate ID's but in PATCH, PUT request it will mention the key which will be provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

Just for sharing the knowledge.

if you are using fire-sharp, you can create the custom key as follows

```
            IFirebaseConfig config = new FirebaseConfig
            {
                AuthSecret = "SecretKey",
                BasePath = "https://abc.firebaseio.com/",
                Host = "abc.firebaseio.com/"
            };
            IFirebaseClient client = new FirebaseClient(config);

            var obj = new Users
            {
                FirstName = "test",
                MiddleName = "user",
                LastName = "xyz"

            };

            SetResponse response = client.SetAsync("Profile", "YourID");//you can use Set() as well
            response = client.SetAsync("Profile/YourID", obj);//you can use Set() as well
```

Answer (score 0):

if database reference child is fixed string, new value will not add. just it will update the previous value. for example :

`DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String mText = // get data from editText or set your own custom data`

now if I insert data like this:

`myRef.child("abc").child("cba").setValue(mText);`

every time I insert data it will update my previous data. It will not add new data. Because my reference is fixed here(`myRef.child("abc").child("cba")` // this one, which is always fixed).

Now change the the value of child "cba" to a random or dynamic value which will not fix. For example:

`Random rand = new Random();
// Obtain a number between [0 - 49].
int n = rand.nextInt(50);
myRef.child("abc").child(String.valueOf(n)).setValue(mText);`

In this case it will add a new value instead of updating. because this time reference is not fixed here. it is dynamic. push() method exactly do the same thing. it generates random key to maintain unique reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node.js to write to firebase Realtime Database here's a function:

```
function registerVibinScores( reference, childId, dataToWrite){

    var ref = db.ref(reference); //vibinScores
    usersRef = ref.child(childId);
    usersRef.set(
        dataToWrite
    );

}

//Example to invoke it:
var vibinEntry = {
    "viberId": "425904090208534528",
    "person": {
        "name": "kukur",
        "score": 0,
        "id": "425904090208534528"
    },
    "vibinScore": 0,
    "timeOfEntry": "2021-04-19T16:59:23.077Z"
}

registerVibinScores('vibinScores/allEntries', 112, vibinEntry);
```

[The sample entry in your database would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i2jO.png)

Answer (score -1):

Simple and Fast

```
 Map<String,Object> taskMap = new HashMap<>();
       taskMap.put("Name", name.getText().toString());
       taskMap.put("km", km.getText().toString());
      // taskMap.put("age", "45");
       taskMap.put("Day", day.getText().toString());
       mDatabaseReference.push().setValue(taskMap);
```