# firebase cloud functions set custom keys

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-datastore, cloud

As push in firebase database generates random key I want it to be custom key like: may be starts with N1,N2,N3... instead of random keys to the child nodes(as shown in pic)[database structure tree that my hardware is updating in cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBWNu.jpg).
I am new to JS so could someone help me formulate the snippet or code.
I am able to deploy some github functions to firebase cloud but, I need help in writing appropriate code for my use case.
I followed this link ( [Setting custom key when pushing new data to firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483406/setting-custom-key-when-pushing-new-data-to-firebase-database/37483668#37483668) ) but,what I understand there is each every child node with random key I have to separately set (rectify me if wrong) and it's not possible for many child nodes present so, can someone help write an appropriate code for my use case. I am complete beginer so please excuse me if I am asking too many questions for clarification.

Comment: Consider formatting this question appropriately to improve readability.

Comment: You should continue to use the firebase push keys - it guarantees unique keys. Whereas if you try and make a custom key like `N1`, `N2` then chances are you might duplicate a key if two users write data at the same time.

Comment: This is for testing alone right know I wanna know how I can do it so,if you could help me in that regard