# Firebase - How i change the field that circled to user ID

Tags: android, firebase

How can i change this unclear field (Medu9EJxCvMNCaPpmLH) to user id?

[image]

this is the code-

[image]

Comment: You cannot change documentId's. If you want to make it different, the document will need to be read in and then written back out with the updated documentId. If you are just asking how to generate documentId's, see the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase documentId's cannot be changed.

If you want to make it different, the document will need to be read in and then written back out with the updated documentId.

If you are just asking how to generate custom documentId's, see [Setting Custom DocumentId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483406/setting-custom-key-when-pushing-new-data-to-firebase-database)